# TwistOAuthでTwitterから送られてくるプライベートヘッダ(RateLimit等)を取得したい

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

TwitterAPIでGET/POSTしたときにレスポンスのヘッダにあるRateLimitを取りたいのですが例えば `get()` で返してくる結果は綺麗にオブジェクトとして整形してくれています。

```
/**
 * Execute GET request.
 *
 * @param string $url      full or partial endpoint URL.
 *                         e.g. "statuses/show", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json"
 * @param mixed  [$params] 1-demensional array or query string.
 * @param string [$proxy]  full proxy URL.
 *                         e.g. https://111.222.333.444:8080
 * @return mixed
 * @throws TwistException
 */
public function get($url, $params = array(), $proxy = '') {
    $ch = $this->curlGet($url, $params, $proxy);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return self::decode($ch, $response);
}
```

`get()`の代わりに`TwistOAuth::curlGet()`と`TwistOAuth::decode()`を使い、`curlGet()`の結果から拾うべきでしょうか？
でも`decode()`は`private`ですから外部からアクセスできませんが。

すみません、当方web系自体が初心者のため見当違いの事を言っているかもしれません。
(コード改造しないでも取れる等)

お手数をお掛けしますが、御教示ください。

---

補足です。TwistOAuth 3.5.2を使っています。

Answer (score 1):

`curl_exec()`も実行する必要はありますが、あとはご想像の通り `TwistOAuth::get()` を改造するか、あるいは・・・というところかと思います。

GithubやTwitterで作者の方に相談してみるといいかもしれません。

Comment: やはり改造なりしないとダメそうですね。
ありがとうございます。
作者さんのツイッターを見つけたので、相談してみます！